# MySQL table not visible in Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I executed the below code to create a table USER and everything looks fine since when I try to execute it again, I get the error *"Table 'USER' already exists"*.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    sqlDB mysqlConnect = new sqlDB();
    Statement stmt = mysqlConnect.connect().createStatement();

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE USER " +
            "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
            " first VARCHAR(255), " +
            " last VARCHAR(255), " +
            " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";
    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        PreparedStatement statement = mysqlConnect.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mysqlConnect.disconnect();
    }
}
```

My question is why don't I see this table in MySQL Workbench?

I checked the section 'Schemas' but there I have only 1 db 'sys' which is not the one I created.

[image: ExampleView]

Comment: I found the solution by following these steps:Open MySQL Workbench.
From the tabs at the top of the window, select ‘Edit->Preferences… ‘.
From within the Workbench Preferences window, click on ‘SQL Editor’.
In the Sidebar section of the SQL Editor window, check the box titled ‘Show Metadata and Internal Schemas’, then click ‘OK’. The Workbench Preferences window will now close.
In the Navigator pane of the Workbench, go to the SCHEMAS section, and click the refresh icon.[/list]

Comment: You should post that as an **answer**, and accept it after the timeout.

Comment: BTW, the line `PreparedStatement statement = mysqlConnect.connect().prepareStatement(sql);` makes no sense in your code, and leaks a statement and a connection.

Answer (score 0):

User is a mysql system table;
You can create a new db and create the table new db.Tablename;